# Check if localStorage isset or not

Tags: html, local-storage

I want to check if localStorage is isset or not.
e.g. i am creating sample localstrorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('TODO_LIST', 'value');
```

Now, i want to check on page load whether localStorage with name `TODO_LIST` is isset or not, also if it is isset how to check whether it blank or not.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
If (localStorage.getItem('TODO_LIST') && localStorage.getItem('TODO_LIST') !== '') {
    // Do something when it's set and not empty
}
```

`localStorage.getItem('TODO_LIST')` returns `null` or falsy when it's not set.

`localStorage.getItem('TODO_LIST') !== ''` returns `true` if it's not empty.